# What is a more functional way of creating a Map of List?

Tags: scala

I have this working code to create a Map between the characters in a String, and a List containing the indexes.

```
scala> "Lollipop".zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Map[Char, List[Int]]())((acc, t) => acc + (t._1 -> (acc.getOrElse(t._1, List[Int]()) :+ t._2)))
res122: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,List[Int]] = Map(i -> List(4), L -> List(0), l -> List(2, 3), p -> List(5, 7), o -> List(1, 6))
```

But the use of `acc.getOrElse` looks imperative. 
Is there a more functional way that hides this from the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for {
  (c, l) <- "Lollipop".zipWithIndex.groupBy{ _._1 }
} yield c -> l.map{ _._2 }
// Map(i -> Vector(4), L -> Vector(0), l -> Vector(2, 3), p -> Vector(5, 7), o -> Vector(1, 6))
```

After `groupBy{ _._1 }` you'll get a `Map[Char, Seq[(Char, Int)]]`. So you have to convert pairs `(Char, Int)` to `Int`, using `p => p._2` or just `_._2`.

You could use `mapValues`like this:

```
"Lollipop".zipWithIndex.groupBy{ _._1 }.mapValues{ _.map{_._2} }
```

But `mapValues` creates a lazy collection, so you could get a performance issue in case of multiple access to the same element by key.

Comment: Thanks! So the significant function in converting a `List` to a `Map` is `groupBy`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative is to use default value for your map (rewritten code a little bit to be more explicit):

```
val empty = Map.empty[Char, List[Int]].withDefaultValue(List.empty)
"Lollipop".zipWithIndex.foldLeft(empty) {
  case (acc, (char, position)) => {
    val positions = acc(char) :+ position
    acc + (char -> positions)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this feels imperative with the `acc(char)` lookup.